# Django valueError when using query_params

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to setup an API using Django. In my views.py, I have this endpoint:

```
@api_view()
def update_label(request):
    user_id = request.query_params['user_id']
    date = datetime.strptime(request.query_params['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
    label_name = request.query_params['label_name']
    value = request.query_params['value']
    value = eval(value)
    db_user_ctrl.update_label(date, user_id, label_name, value)
    return Response({'status': 'SUCCESS'})
```

It updates some label in the database for some user. Multiple labels can be updated from this endpoint, some associate `value` with an integer, some associate `value` with a small dictionary e.g. `{'item1':1,'item2':-1}`. On the javascript side I use `JSON.stringify(value)` to format the value before sending it via a GET request. On the Django part, I can see the proper parameters have been recieved through the debugging interface. However I have the following error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '{"item1":-1}'
```

Associated with this line in my code:

```
value = request.query_params['value']
```

What is happening here? Why is he trying to casting the string into an integer?

**EDIT 1:**

Some more info on the stack trace:

```
.../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
.../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
.../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py in wrapped_view
.../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py in view
.../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in dispatch
.../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py in dispatch
.../venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py in handler
.../webapp/api/views.py in update_label
    value = request.query_params['value']
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, if you can. Because my first guess would have been that the problem is actually `eval(value)`. Which you should not do, by the way, because you have a remote code execution problem right there.

Comment: Not sure why you're using eval here at all. Not only is it unnecessary, but seems a particularly bad idea to call it on unvalidated user input.

Comment: I use eval to transform a string into a python object, maybe there are safer ways to do this but I dont think this is where the problem is. I tried to comment the eval line, and got the same error. The query params should be interpreted as strings, and all the other parameters are ! For some reasons django tries to cast this one into an int.

Comment: That's not the stack trace, that's a list of lines. Please show the full thing.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
import json
json.loads(<query string value>)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was quite sneaky, it was due to Gunicorn caching some files. In the old versions of `views.py`, I had `value = int(request.query_params['value'])`. When I updated the code Gunicorn was still answering using the outdated cached files, hence the failure to cast a string into an int. I restarted Gunicorn and it's working now.